# Pasting a form into a string (with str_replace) is not working

Tags: php

I'd like to paste a signup form into a text (let's call it $mystring) with str_replace.
The basic idea is to change [signup] to SignUp($parameters) in a text.
Finally to echo it: `echo $mystring`

So it would look like this:

```
Some text
A working sign up form
Some text
```

**My problem:**
The form works properly, but because of the echoes used in it, it **appears before the output** of $mystring. I'd like it to show up inside the text.

The code here inserts the function into the string, no problem:

```
$mystring = str_replace("[signup]",SignUp($parameters),$mystring);
```

Function SignUp() looks like this:

```
if (!isset($_POST["btn"])) SignUpForm($parameters); // here I show the form if post is empty
else
{
   // here I check the values then do some DB inserts if correct
   echo $successmessage (or echo $errormessage)
}
```

Function SignUpForm() contains a HTML form:

```
echo "<form method='post' action=''>
```

...and the rest with the input fields and submit button.
Also note the usage of echo here.

So with using the echoes in the two functions, it works flawlessly however it is not displayed inside the text, but before the output of $mystring **because of the echoes placed in the functions that are also echoed as echo $mystring.**

Changing the echoes to returns does not do the job, the form is not displayed at all.

What should I do to avoid echoing in an echo, to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Don't echo inside of functions, always return strings.

```
$mystring = str_replace("[signup]",SignUp($parameters),$mystring);
echo $mystring;

function SignUp($parameters){
    global $_POST;
    if (!isset($_POST["btn"])){
        return SignUpForm($parameters); // here I show the form if post is empty
    } else {
       // here I check the values then do some DB inserts if correct
       return ($successmessage) ?: $errormessage;
    }
}

function SignUpForm(){
    return "<form method='post' action=''>";
}
```

Comment: SignUp function isn't returning anything because none of the strings are being set. I edited my answer to add `global $_POST` which would not be within scope inside of that function.  This will enable the isset() test to work properly if the 'btn' param was not posted.  You'll also want to look at how `$successmessage` and `$errormessage` are set.  As it's written, these will always be blank.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I see what I've done wrong: I simply didn't return the SignUpForm() function -> ```return SignUpForm()```...
That made the trick. It makes sense, somehow I overlooked it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggesting using the `SignUp()` function directly in `str_replace()` since there are alternate outcomes and it doesn't always return the string you need. Maybe this will work for you.

```
function SignUpForm(){
    return "<form method='post' action=''>";
}

function SignUp($parameters){
    if (!isset($_POST["btn"])){
        return SignUpForm($parameters); // here I show the form if post is empty
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}

$signUp = SignUp($parameters);
if ($signUp) {
    $mystring = str_replace("[signup]", $signUp, $mystring);
} else {
    echo $successmessage (or echo $errormessage);
}

echo $mystring;
```